# What's causing this intelhax.m error in the Windows 10 System log?

Tags: windows, bsod

Windows 10 crashes intermittently, but when it does, the system log always shows the same error: Intelhax.m  Any suggestions on why that's occurring.

[image: System Log Error]

Comment: The first thing I would do is **uninstall** [Intel HAXM](https://github.com/intel/haxm)

Comment: I am positive that error is saying `Intelhaxm` cannot be found not `Intelhax.m`